# data import wizard mysql table exists but does not appear under 'use existing table'

Tags: mysql, data-import

I'm trying to import data via excel, however, after the table data import wizard appears and I select 'use existing tables' the picklist is empty even though I have several schema's and tables

[Click for image - Data Import Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB4Ki.png)

[Click for image - MySQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4ySq.png)

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Don't ask a question where the title includes the word "solved".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Historically, I used the data import wizard while I'm viewing the table I want to import data to, inside the result grid where there's a 'Export/Import' section further to the right on the same row and I click the icon that has a grid on the back and a folder with an arrow pointing up. This is where I was facing the issue of an empty pick-list next to 'use existing tables'.

As an alternative, I right clicked the 'Tables' in the schema section and chose 'Table Data Import' and from here my tables come up under 'use existing tables'.

Not sure what the root cause is but problem solved.